# Swift how to remove uisegmentControl default black backgroundColor?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I know a lot of people asked this question, but nothing helps. My controller1 presents a new controller2 from storyboard. Controler1's background color is black. My customized segmentcontrol background color and selectedTintColor work well, but always show a black background color first. I tried every way, but not working. In storyboard and code, all no this black color. Thanks!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let bgColor = uIColor. // my customized color)
    segmentControl.backgroundColor = bgColor
}

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    connectionSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    toggleSegmentTintColor()
}

private func toggleSegmentTintColor() {
   // I set my customized selected tint color here, it works.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this in viewDidAppear, its too late: the view is on the screen.  The hack way to do it is in viewDidlaod or viewWillAppear.  The right way to do it is to to use UIAppearance proxy on app launch to set the tint color for your object globally:

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.clear
```

You can also set the tint color for the whole app by setting it on the root window, but then it affects more than just the segmented controls.